# oData Continuation when projects target framework is 3.5

Tags: c#, odata

I have a oData query like this

```
var Info= from p in context.Information                       
where p.InformationSource.Equals("TopSecret")...
order by p.Date
select p;
```

And I go through the data like this

```
foreach (var info in Info) {...}
```

The problem is that if project target framework is .NET Framework 4.0 I can do this

```
while (info.InformationSource.Continuation != null)
{
    info.InformationSource.Load(context.Execute(info.InformationSource.Continuation));
}
```

because  the product.InformationSource is of type DataServiceCollection

but in 3.5 framework it is of type Collection and I can't do .Continuation with that.

Question is: How do I get all the data from the feed when using target framework is 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

DataServiceCollection and Continuation(paging) support should be available in the latest 3.5SP1 update.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=79d7f6f8-d6e9-4b8c-8640-17f89452148e&displaylang=en
or
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4B710B89-8576-46CF-A4BF-331A9306D555

Prior to this update, the data services client did not have paging support and should get all the data from the feed.
Hope this helps.

Comment: With 3.5 and 4.0 I get the same amount of objects in info (300) but with 4.0 I can use .Continuation to fetch the rest. With 3.5 I can't do it because of the type (Collection)